# Why do we use ethanol in SN2 reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, solvents

Solomons and Fryhle has an example in which they have showed a very simple substitution reaction. The question was to synthesize methyl iodide. What they have done is taken methyl chloride and produced methyl iodide in the presence of $\ce{NaI}$ and ethanol through an $\mathrm{S_N2}$ mechanism.

Why did they use ethanol? I have read that $\mathrm{S_N2}$ reactions are favored under polar aprotic solvents and clearly ethanol is not that. Also, since it's a methyl and all substitution reactions on methyl go through $\mathrm{S_N2}$; so how would it affect my reaction if I would't use ethanol?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usually, nucleophilic substitution reactions of anionic nucleophiles occur more rapidly in polar aprotic solvents. In such solvents (e.g. DMSO) the typical relative reactivity order is
$$ \ce{SCN-} < \ce{I-} < \ce{Br-} < \ce{Cl-} < \ce{F-}$$

In protic hydrogen-bonding solvents (e.g. ethanol), anions are solvated. Therefore, the reactivity of nucleophiles is decreased. Since hard nucleophiles are more strongly solvated than soft nucleophiles, the *relative* reactivity of soft anions is increased in such solvents. The typical relative reactivity order is
$$ \ce{F-} < \ce{Cl-} < \ce{Br-} < \ce{I-} < \ce{SCN-}$$

In the given example, $\ce{-Cl}$ shall be replaced by $\ce{-I}$; and in alcohols, the nucleophilicity of $\ce{I-}$ is higher than the nucleophilicity of $\ce{Cl-}$.

Answer (score 4):

When compared to some polar, aprotic solvents, such as acetonitrile or dimethyl formamide, ethanol has a couple of advantages:

- it is rather cheap
- it is less toxic
- **the solubility of sodium iodide is rather high**

Comment: So you mean to say that it is suited only for this reaction of many other substitution reactions also?

Comment: Please see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you find the statement: "all substitution reactions on methyl go through $S_N1$"? It is obviously wrong. Methyl definitely favor $S_N2$.

Here is the answer. The conversion from $\ce{MeCl}$ to $\ce{MeI}$ go through $S_N2$ mechanism. The best solvent for $\ce{-Cl}$ to $\ce{-I}$ conversion is usually **acetone**. It is cheap, polar aprotic, good solubility for $\ce{NaI}$ and poor solubility for $\ce{NaCl}$. I think the reason to use ethanol is just because this reaction is too easy to be picky on solvent. It just works in ethanol.

Comment: Also what do you mean by "too easy to be picky on solvent"? And what if I don't use ethanol or any other solvent(I mean just NaI and and MeCl). I am sorry if a reaction without that a solvent sounds weird -I have next to zero experience in a lab, so I don't know which one is present in a solid or liquid form!

Comment: Neat (no solvent) condition is not possible because $MeCl$ is gas at room temperature.